# the specific usage of the word "predicate"

Tags: meaning

As the Oxford Dictionary puts it, one of the meaning of "predicate" is to asser something about someone or something, but It gives an example I cannot get. Here goes: "Aggression is predicated of those who act aggressivly". I suppose this means that people who act aggressivly embody agression itself, tell me please if I am right or wrong

Comment: Windbaggery is predicated of those who speak in that manner.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo's comment is an eloquent way of saying you are right.  Think of it this way, "Aggression comes of those who act aggressively."  In the sense we're using it, "predicated of" means "comes of" or "the result of" or "is the nature of."  *And I have seriously proven an adage I once heard about windbaggery....* :-)